# How to set the space between two index entries with the same character

Tags: spacing, indexing, line-spacing

When I make an index, I get only between the different characters (b,s,t) an optimal vertical spacing.

```
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\index{book}
\index{summer!sun}
\index{summer!heat}
\index{sound}
\index{tower}
```

Because I've only a few index entries, the vertical spacing between summer and sound (starting with the same character) should be the same as for different letters like (book and summer or sound and tower: one blank line of 1em).

I've tried to find for a solution in the internet and in the package documentation but was not successful.

Is this somehow possible with makeidx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\@idxitem` to have a vertical space preceding it, while `\indexspace` does nothing. Also `\subitem` needs to be redefined, otherwise it would add the vertical space as well.

For separating the first entry from the heading, a `\vspace{12pt}` instruction is added to `\theindex`, modify it to suit.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
\def\indexspace{}
\patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
x
\index{book}
\index{summer!sun}
\index{summer!heat}
\index{summer!heat!sweat}
\index{sound}
\index{tower}

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<40
\advance\count255 1
\expandafter\index\expandafter{\romannumeral\count255}
\repeat

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `arara` directives are what I used to ease compilation; the `\loop` just fills in some more index entries so we arrive at the second column.

[image]

If I change the code above into

```
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{5\p@ \@plus 2.5\p@ \@minus 1.5\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
\renewcommand\indexspace{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}}
\patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

then the space between different letters will be double of the space between entries starting with the same letter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very cool. However I have a list with several indixes and therefore a two column index. The problem is that the secon column begins at higher position than the first column. With playing with vspace I was able to `\appto\theindex{\vspace*{-2.22em}}` adjust both beginnings of the two columns but they don't begin exactly at the same hight. Is this somehow possible to do this automatically?

Comment: Thank you. Please consider to add `\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 70\p@ \hspace*{40\p@}}` because I need a subsubentry. Thank you!

Comment: @laminin Look at the fix

Comment: I tried another texteditor. There I get a notification: command is not recognized. Will ``\addvspace`` and ``\theindex`` also be recognized with other documentclasses like `\documentclass[twoside,ngerman,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}` or do I need to add something?

Comment: @laminin I can do nothing if the editor doesn't recognize commands. This is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I'd like to have only half of the vertical spacing between the entries of different starting letters (e.g. summer and tower). Which number of ``\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}`` do I have to change?

Comment: You have to do `\renewcommand{\indexspace}{\addvspace{10pt}}` and reduce the spacing in `\@idxitem` to 5pt (with the appropriate flexibility components).

Comment: Thank you egreg! Without using ``\renewcommand{\indexspace}{\addvspace{10pt}}`` I got a nice layout just by changing your initial code with: ``\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{20\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 40\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}``

Comment: When I change this values unfortunately it changes also the line spacing of my ``\nomenclature{symbol}{text}``. Is it possible to change your code, so it acts only on the ``index``?

Comment: @laminin Yes, put the code for redefining `\@idxitem` and siblings when you do `\printindex` (maybe adding a group around them): `\begingroup<the code>\printindex\endgroup`

Comment: Okay thank you. Unfortunately it did not work, but I will try to get an adequate solution.